# rails: google affiliate network API oauth when API does not support Service Account model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0

Update 1: as I delve deeper, this isn't really anything to do with Rails, it's more of a question about how to have a server access our account using credentials provided by Google when the API we're calling *doesn't support the Service Model*

I have a server application that needs to connect to Google API from Rails.  I can authenticate with OAuth2 successfully using the google-api-ruby-client gem and get other APIs working.  There are several samples that use the gem, but most assume you want a user to authenticate themselves in a web environment.  Others support what Google calls a "Service Model" where it's really the app validating itself.  I have that working, too.

However the specific API I am querying is Google Affiliate Network (GAN), which does not support the Service Account model.  In particular, I need a server to be able to authenticate with OAuth2 without any user interaction.  I have done this using OAuth in several other contexts, but am struggling to get it working in this case.

Does anyone know of working Rails code for GAN?

Update 2: I am searching [this google document on API authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for strategies that don't require user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workable solution -- it uses Google's "Installed Application" approach, which needs one bit of manual setup, but is otherwise a working solution.

https://gist.github.com/3543368